# A simple mathematical induction proof.

Tags: induction

Let n be a natural number, and let $ f:\{ i \in \mathbb{N}  : 1 \le i \le n\} \rightarrow\mathbb{N} $ be a function. Show that there exists a natural number M such that $f(i) \le M $ for $1 \le i \le n $

We prove this by induction on n, when n = 1, $f(i) \le M $ for $1\le i \le1$. since if M := 1, the above holds.

now suppose that we have already proven the proposition for some $ n \ge 1$, we have to prove it for $n++$,
by the induction hypothesis, we know that there exists a natural number $ M $ such that $f(i) \le M $ for $1 \le i \le n $, in particular there must exist a natural number $ M+1$, in which case $f(i) \le M +1 $ for $1 \le i \le n++ $

Could someone shed some light on whether i have logically proved this?

Comment: No, you have not proved this. It looks like you are assuming that $f(n+1)=M+1$, which is by no means true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't proved it because neither your base-case argument nor your induction step argument is correct.

For example, when $n=1$, suppose $f$ is the function that sends $1$ to $5$.  You claim that if $M=1$ then $f(i)\le M$ when $i=1$.  But $f(1)=5>1=M$.  **What do you need to do to fix this?**

As for the induction step, when $n=2$, $f$ might be the function that sends $1$ to $1$ and $2$ to $1$.  So if we choose $M=1$, then $f(i)\le M$ for each $i$.  But now,, if $g$ is the function that sends $1$ to $1$, $2$ to $1$ and $3$ to $5$, then it is not the case that $f(i)\le M+1$ for each $i$.  Indeed $f(3)=5>2=M+1$.  **What do you need to do to fix this?**

Comment: $M = f(1)$ for the first question. I'm not so sure about the second, would $M := f(n+1)?$

Comment: @HMPARTICLE **Hint:** suppose $f(i)=1000$ for $i=1,\dots,n$ and $f(n+1)=1$.  Does setting $M=f(n+1)$ work in that case?  And how are you going to use the fact that the proposition is true for $n$ to deduce that it's true for $n+1$?

Comment: You're very close though!

Comment: AH would i introduce a new variable. say M' and let M' be the largest value taken by either M or f(n+1), using the fact that the proposition is true for n? since  M is the upper bound for when n is true

Comment: @HMPARTICLE Yes, that's basically the right idea.  Try and write the whole proof out in full now!

Comment: We prove this by induction on n, when n = 1, f(i)≤M for 1≤i≤1.if we choose M := f(1), the above holds.

now suppose that we have already proven the proposition for some n≥1, we have to prove it for n++, by the induction hypothesis, we know that there exists a natural number M such that f(i)≤M for 1≤i≤n, in particular there must exist a natural number M':=max{M,f(n+1)}, in which case f(i)≤M' for 1≤i≤n++. I honestly feel like this proves it?

Comment: Yes - well done.  That's the right answer.

Comment: As a small nitpick - it's better to write something like this: 'If $M\ge f(n+1)$, then let $M'=M$; otherwise, let $M'=f(n+1)$', rather than just writing $M'=\max\{M,f(n+1)\}$.  The reason for this is that the point of this induction proof is to show that you can take the $\max$ of an arbitrary finite set; indeed, if you know this, then you can just let $M=\max\{f(1),\dots,f(n)\}$ and you're done immediately.

Comment: No, thank you, i shall alter my notes asap, could i ask you to look at another proof? i posted it on this site,http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076474/197848 . @Donkey_2009

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know something about $f$ that you haven't written, you haven't proven it.

In you base step you say that $M=1$ makes it hold, but $f$ might be $2$ for all natural numbers.

As Ian points out in his comment, you induction step also uses assumptions about $f$ that you don't know.

A hint on how you might show it:

$\{i\in\mathbb N:1\leq i\leq n\}$ is a finite set.